# Structures in asm

Tags: assembly

I'm studying do structures without macros (pure assembly).

Imagine the function and the structure

```
foo(struct house* ip)
    house{
    short a;
    short b;
    int c;
    }
```

And the program in assembly:

```
push 0   ; c = 0
pushw 11 ; b = 11
pushw 0  ; a = 0

mov ecx, esp ; pointer to the structure
execute->foo(ecx)
```

Two questions:
1. Structs in asm must have NULL after the structure? I've seen some codes that put null and others no.
2. How know "asm" esp reference to my structure? Variables are referenced by ebp+nº bytes

Answer (score 0):

There is no requirement that structs have a NULL after them in assembly.

`esp` always points to what you just pushed on stack, and as you correctly assume the stack grows downward in memory.

However you can't set up an arbitrary structure using push, like you are attempting here.

A stack entry has a certain fixed width (normally either 16, 32, or 64 bits) depending on the mode the CPU is running in, so your approach only works if all the elements in the struct happen to have a width, which is a multiple of that of a stack entry.

Comment: Code updated. My question is how know the function foo he must choose esp, esp-2 and esp-2. Ok! I will be more specific. When in this code https://gist.github.com/geyslan/5174296 at line 71 I call to bind, the syscall take the structure put in the stack, but if the structure is in .data and I say to bind() my structure isn't in esp-nº. Do you know what am I trying to doing?

Comment: If you have another question; post it as a separate question instead of using the comments field of a previous answer. And remember to include the relevant code directly in your question rather thank linking to it.

Comment: It isn't another question.